# How to change launcher activity

Tags: java, android

I imported one eclipse project into android studio, which have one main activity "MainActivity". Now I created a second activity "Main2Activity". I want to assign this (Main2Activity) as launcher activity. When user install the app the second app should open first.

I also tried to change the AndroidManifest file as given below, but no luck...

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myapp.mytime.Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.myapp.mytime.MainActivity"></activity>
```

Could any one help?

Comment: post your whole code of manifestFile

Comment: clean your project than after rebuild project and again RUN

Comment: Does your problem resolve??@Nim

Comment: No, not yet. As suggested by others I cleaned, rebuild but no luck

Comment: Please check your `Main2Activity.Java` file i think there is  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` instead of this  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);` -@Nim

Comment: Does it work??@Nim

Comment: I checked in Main2Activity.java, it was there as you said...Yes, Now work...After refreshing several time.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for help....Now working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your `Main2Activity.Java` file i think there is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` instead of this `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);`

Answer (score 0):

As I've seen you have this code on your `Main2Activity`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You just have to clean your project and press run. You should be good to go.

Comment: I cleaned as u said, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.mytime.Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.myapp.mytime.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also Check if you load **MainActivity** programmatically or not and Also **Clean** the project. and remove the application from device before running on it after doing these changes.

Comment: I did as your gave the code above, cleaned and rebuild but not working...

Comment: "load MainActivity programmatically" what is this?? How should I do this?